# Why is this simple html and css code not showing anything?

Tags: html, css

html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="qa.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#wrap {
width:750px;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
background:#008B00;
}
```

The html file is called qa.html, and the css file is called qa.css
The two files are in the same directory.

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: a green div block that fills the middle 750 pixels of the page.

Comment: The height of elements isn't set automatically. Did you try changing the 'height' and 'display' attributes of #wrap?

Comment: I gave body and wrap elements height:100%;   still nothing...

Comment: Have you tried it without the css tag?  I think you should start with what you have and continue to make it simpler until it works, then start adding stuff back.  Use tools like firebug (or IE developer tools) and view source to determine what's going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Um... How's the HTML supposed to show anything if there's no content?

[EDIT] To make it more specific and not sound like I'm complaining: put some content in the wrapper div, otherwise it's empty and thus with 0 height.

[EDIT 2]: According to the expected output you describe in the comment, you want the div to take up 100% height of the document. You need to specify this explicitly, ie body and #wrap need to have height:100%. Or even better, min-height.

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="qa.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap"><p>Hello</p></div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#wrap {
  width: 750px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background: #008B00;
  min-height: 100%;
}

Comment: The height values are the key here.

Answer (score 3):

The `div` will collapse upon itself if there is no content *and* no height set. Either put some text or content into the `div`, or set a min-height or height explicitly.

**Edit: please put a doctype in your pages; it helps a lot with expected renderings.**

Comment: i put content in the div, and the page doesn't show anything. Any other possibilities as to what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> a green div block that fills the middle 750 pixels of the page.

So,

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#wrap {
    width: 750px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #008B00;
}
```

?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm suggesting as well. Confirmed working, at least in Chrome ;)

Comment: The key is giving `height: 100%` to `html` as well.

Comment: I've heard others claim this, but no, body is actually enough.